# c# wpf catch win key code from previewkeydown event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, keystrokes

i need to obtain the windows low level key code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx ) intercepting input from `UIElement.PreviewKeyDown()` for send it via socket and share these with another host.
Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is how you use it:

```
private void previewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
   var vk = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
   //....
}
```